# Server side request forgery--fortify scan

Tags: c#, web-services, request, fortify

in my **C#** application below method it is hitting service and returning data. At the return statement there was a fortify scan issue raised under the category named Server side request forgery. There is no parameter adding to URL in the method. uri as is used to fetch data. I am completely new.

```
 using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
    return JsonObject.GetDynamicJsonObject(wc.DownloadString(uri.ToString())); //here issue raised
}
```

Comment: is this `uri` (or any part of it) provided by end user (on the report check the `source`, what you have shown is the `sink`)? if so, then yes, ssrf is possible. you will need to validate `uri` somewhere to ensure its only on select few allowed domains (if applicable).